# Java Swing - getting char from ResultSet

Tags: java, swing, resultset

As per the following codes:

```
char Secgrp = 0;
    try{
        String a = (String) comboName.getSelectedItem();
        String fill = "Select recDate, attendant, grp from log order by id DESC";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(fill);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        String x = cDate();
        while (rs.next()){

            java.sql.Date dDate = rs.getDate("recDate");
            String bName = rs.getString("attendant");
            char[] cbuf = new char[1];
            rs.getCharacterStream("grp").read(cbuf);
            char theValue = cbuf[0];
            String grp = Character.toString(theValue);


            if(x.equals(dDate.toString()) && group1 == theValue && a.equals(bName)){
               Secgrp = theValue++ ;
            } 
          else if(x.equals(dDate.toString()) && theValue > group1 && a.equals(bName))  
            { Secgrp = theValue++;
            }
            else if(x.equals(dDate.toString()) && group1 > theValue && a.equals(bName))           
           { Secgrp = group1;
            }
```

As per the above codes, I'm trying to check if a char is equal to my resultset record. e.g. if A is equal to A, if date = date and name = name than do something.

But when I setText(String.valueOf(Secgrp)), no char is being inserted.

Please advice how can I retrieve a char e.g 'A' from resultSet.

Comment: I don't see `diveGrp` in your SELECT statement. Are you sure you typed the query in correctly? What data type is it in the db?

Comment: Its a char data type in db.

Comment: Ok, I see the changes you made to your code now. I don't think your problem is with the char field, but with your date comparison. Given that you have no real control over how `date.toString()` will be formatted, you really do the comparison on real date objects.

Comment: I did a test to my code. If date equals date, grp equals grp and name equals name then setText "Z". It worked. I suppose its the char increment. Any idea?

Comment: You might want to include the code where you are using the `Secgrp` variable to set the widget text. Also, are you logging its value before the set?

Comment: Char Secgrp =0, after comparing the results will be stored into e variable which is Secgrp = theValue++ e.g the result is "A++" it still came out as "A" whereas should be B.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23118/discussion-between-perception-and-user1815586)

Comment: Does anyone have any idea if I do get a char from DB and increment it using "++" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Add breaks after each blocks

```
       if(x.equals(dDate.toString()) && group1 == theValue && a.equals(bName)){
           Secgrp = theValue++ ;
         Break;
        } 
      else if(x.equals(dDate.toString()) && theValue > group1 && a.equals(bName))  
        { Secgrp = theValue++;
        Break;
        }
        else if(x.equals(dDate.toString()) && group1 > theValue && a.equals(bName))           
       { Secgrp = group1;
         Break;
        }
```

Comment: What is `Break`? How would it help?

Comment: The reason why my previous codes aint working. It scan my rs from 1st to last record without a break if even when a blocm is executed.  So I added in a break; when e rs scan the records and block is executed it will stop.

Comment: Ah, you mean `break`; `Break` looked like a class name.